# Can not update Bugzilla Parameters

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, bugzilla

I'm running Bugzilla 4.4.5 on Windows 2008 r2 with IIS 7.5. My path to Index.cgi is C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\bugzilla-4.4.5

The URL I'm using is `http://localhost/bugzilla`

I can bring the website up and login, but when I edit the parameters and click "Save" I get this message:

```
Software error:
Error in tempfile() using template data\params.XXXXX: Could not create temp file     data\params.I19Ig: Permission denied at Bugzilla/Config.pm line 270.


For help, please send mail to this site's webmaster, giving this error message and the time and date of the error. 
[Wed Sep 17 13:14:16 2014] editparams.cgi: Error in tempfile() using template data\params.XXXXX: Could not create temp file data\params.I19Ig: Permission denied at Bugzilla/Config.pm line 270.
```

I ran process monitor (from sysinternals) on it and noticed this interesting line:

```
"Time of Day","Process Name","PID","Operation","Path","Result","Detail"

"12:11:37.2166449 PM","w3wp.exe","1172","CreateFile","C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\bugzilla-4.4.5\editparams.cgi\web.config","PATH NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a"
```

Any ideas about what I need to change?

ETA:
I verified that permissions for IUSR are Full Control for ALL folders, subfolders & files. No changes were made.

It doesn't work.

Comment: its clearly saying its a permission issue, make sure that where your files resides those are writable by user.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm a total IIS newb.

Comment: I copied the Bugzilla files into a directory under wwwroot. Shouldn't they inherit the wwwroot permissions?

Comment: yes they should but not sure but make sure it should be writable by IIS user if any on windows, I do not have much windows experience.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS, navigate to the settings for the site (or Application if you have set it up as one) and in Features view, open the CGI feature.

Change `Impersonate User` to **False**, and restart IIS (or the site)

Regardless of your Application Pool settings, the CGI setting is forcing Perl to use a user account, which doesn't have permission. This fixed it for me.